# on_member_join can't print a message

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm doing a Discord bot with Python 3.8 and I have a problem with my event `on_member_join()`.

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):

    embed = discord.Embed(
    title=f"that doesn't function")
    channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.channels, name='WELCOME_CHANNEL_NAME')


    await member.send('Hello')
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

`member.send` sends a private message with hello but `channel.send`  sends this error `await channel.send(embed=embed) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'`

I really don't know how to do,

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you probably don't have a channel named `WELCOME_CHANNEL_NAME`. That's why `channel` returns None. You need to type the real welcome channel name instead of `WELCOME_CHANNEL_NAME` in `channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.channels, name='WELCOME_CHANNEL_NAME')`.

Comment: xD i'm so stupid, i thought "WELCOME_CHANNEL_NAME" was the "general" channel, thanks !!!! i would never check that :D